# scallable javascript games

Tags: javascript, html, svg

How is this JavaScript based games scallable? http://www.codedread.com/yastframe.php
When you resize the browser window the games scales nicely to fit the window.

Is it because of the use of SVG?

I also have to create different games/educational lessons and other stuff that I want to fit nicely in any resolution like Flash.

I did read somewhere that SVG is resolution independent. But I've no idea how to take advantage of that.

Answer (score 1):

It's a frameset with the following ratio:

```
cols="130,*,130"
```

The mid frame (the game) width is thus `(page width) - 2 * 130`. The SVG has been set to `width="100%" height="100%"` and will fill the complete mid frame. As you resize your window, the `100%` will become something else when calculated in absolute pixels and the game will resize along.

Since the viewbox is `0 0 800 600`, it will automatically keep the ratio. Try changing it (using a DOM inspector) to e.g. `0 0 800 800`. You will see the game move to the top a little, since the height has become more and the game has to move up to make space.

Comment: so can I create a board game with width and height 600px in JavaScript with absolute positioning and use the above logic to make it scale like that?

I also found http://www.limejs.com/static/roundball/index.html , they also scale really really well.

Comment: No. The `viewBox` of the SVG should have those dimensions, and you shouldn't use absolute positioning.